# stdafx.h does not exist in new New Project Wizard (VS)

Tags: c++, include, precompiled-headers

> cannot open source file `stdafx.h` or `<stdafx.h>`

Yes I understand what precompiled headers are

I have been struggling the past hour trying to get a precompiled header stdafx.h to my project as I'm getting the error:

> "cannot open source file "stdafx.h".

I tried the Precompiled Header list under Project/Properties and tried making a new temporary project that other suggestions say to just copy from there, but the only ones I see come in `<iostream>` instead

I've read every other solution here and I'm frustrated why its still not working.

In my header file, it says its using `stdafx.h`, and I tried both "don't use a precompiled header" and the one I've been suggested through guides. Just want my `stdafx.h` in my code to work.

Followed past posts here in the past(latest 2016)

changed precompiled header list and tested/messed with the options following suggestions

Tried creating a temporary file pulling the header from there, it wasn't there.

Comment: Precompileed header configuration has *nothing* to do with the compiler telling you it cannot even *find* `stdafx.h`. The compiler is telling you that header cannot be *found*; period. Ask yourself why is that? Can *you* open that header? Is it in your vc++ project ? source/headers tree ? Is it in the same disk folder as the rest of your source/header files? I can tell you how to configure pch, but first make damn sure you have the header on which you wish to base pch on even available.

Comment: (If you want to turn them off) Sometimes precompiled headers are turned on on a file-by-file basis, so you may check properties on individual header files too, rather than just the project settings.

Comment: Do you need to use Precompiled Headers?  How much build time has it saved you?  In my experience, the amount of build time is insignificant, especially compared to the side-effects it causes.